# Timedelta is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, nameerror

Below is the code I am working on. From what I can tell there is no issue, but when I attempt to run the piece of code I receive an error.

```
import os 
import datetime

def parseOptions():

    import optparse
    parser = optparse.OptionParser(usage= '-h')
    parser.add_option('-t', '--type', \
                      choices= ('Warning', 'Error', 'Information', 'All'), \
                      help= 'The type of error',
                      default= 'Warning')
    parser.add_option('-g', '--goback', \
                      type= 'string')
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    return options

options = parseOptions() now = datetime.datetime.now() subtract = timedelta(hours=options.goback) difference = now - subtract

if options.type=='All' and options.goback==24:
    os.startfile('logfile.htm')

else: 
    print
    print 'Type =', options.type,
    print
    print 'Go Back =', options.goback,'hours'
    print difference.strftime("%H:%M:%S %a, %B %d %Y")
    print
```

Error is as followed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\SITE-P~1\PYTHON~2\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 325, in RunScript
    exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Python\python.py", line 19, in <module>
    subtract = timedelta(hours=options.goback)
NameError: name 'timedelta' is not defined
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You've imported datetime, but not defined timedelta.  You want either:

```
from datetime import timedelta
```

or:

```
subtract = datetime.timedelta(hours=options.goback)
```

Also, your goback parameter is defined as a string, but then you pass it to timedelta as the number of hours.  You'll need to convert it to an integer, or better still set the `type` argument in your option to `int` instead.

Comment: Perfect, thankyou for all the help.
I think it is much easeier to use:
`datetime.timedelta`
and I have changed the type to int. Thank you again.

Comment: Yes, once you've imported datetime referring to the timedelta class by `datetime.timedelta` would be the usual best practice.  The point is that importing the datetime module gets you all the names it defines, but you do have to reference them through its namespace.  You'll see the general pattern of importing a module and then referencing its contents very often.

Comment: still gives a NameError: name 'timedelta_series' is not defined

Answer (score 3):

It should be `datetime.timedelta`

Answer (score 2):

Where you have `timedelta`, you need to put `datetime.` before it, so it's actually `datetime.timedelta`

Answer (score 0):

I find this problem may occur in some of my sutpid action.
I create a file named datetime.py and even I rename the file, I still leave the datetime.pyc in the folder...
So every file that import dateime will use this file and timedelta cannot be found.
After I delete the file:datetime.pyc, It works.